# How to use azure-devops-ui package in angular project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm working on [Azure Devops extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops) and I've integrated angular with the extension.
Now I want to use [azure-devops-ui](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops) in my extension.
Is it possible to integrate this package in angular project?
If yes, how can we do that?
If no, is there any way to use the Azure DevOps UI components in my extension so that I get the same look & feel as of Azure DevOps' UI?

Currently I'm using vss-web-extension, does it have any UI components which can be used?

Answer (score 0):

The [azure-devops-ui](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/) contains React components. There is no easy way to do this, but you can look at this Microsoft project (you have to wrap the React components):
https://github.com/microsoft/angular-react

Comment: Thanks for the reference.
Is there any way to use the Azure DevOps UI components in my extension apart from azure-devops-ui?

Comment: I don't know other ways, maybe there is a suggestion ticket somewhere on the VS dev community site, but according to this, currently there is no other way: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-tl-use-azure-devops-ui-html-and-css/1296847?viewtype=all